# SDK to create adobe id

Tags: drm, adobe-reader

Does anybody know how to create adobe ids from some api or sdk? I have been looking for a while but I did not found anything yet

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do--are you looking for a solution for using Adobe's DRM for your ebooks or something? That's phenomenally expensive, as I understand it.

Comment: Exactly, right now in my application my user has to enter to the adobe interface and create the account and then generate the fulfillment so they can see the information

Comment: You may also consider that many readers view DRM as a limitation of their rights and prefer to buy ebook without these locks. It will be an hassle for you and a nuisance for them, nobody wins.

Comment: Hi and thanks for asking Could you provide a documentation about it thanks

Comment: I'm not so sure about what you mean with documentation, anyway you could have a look here: http://www.defectivebydesign.org

Answer (score 1):

Adobe does not support this. Adobe does sell (or its partners) have what is known as a Vendor ID that you could build an API around for use in your application.

They do not allow the programmatic creation of Adobe IDs though.